# Pass additional argument in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I have below jquery validation for form, i want to pass additional argument in validation, so while submitting form, that value also pass with form data and send to my php server for processing,

```
var handleAddNewTest = function (filenames) {

    var form1 = $('#test_fm');

        console.log(filenames); //I can see filenames in console output...

        form1.validate({
        rules: {
                test_date: {
                    required: true,
                },
        .....
        .....
        submitHandler: function(form) {
                console.log(filenames); //I cant see in console output, it shows undefined.
        some ajax....
     });

}
```

How can i take filenames values to submitHandler of jquery validation plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass it to submitHandler function as a parameter:

```
    submitHandler: function(form, filenames) {
            console.log(filenames); 
 }
```

Comment: form1.validate({ is itself a function, so how can i go in .validate()?

Comment: ohhh, than you should use custom validator https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Comment: i don't want to validate it with extra argument, i have to just pass this argument as value in ajax